# How To Trigger The "Pressed Effect" Or "Highlight Effect" Of A UIButton When Other UIButton Is Pressed

Tags: ios, user-interface, uibutton

I have a big UIButton with a background image, and five small invisible UIButtons on top of it. I want to trigger the highlight effect of the big button when one of the small invisible buttons is pressed. How can I achieve this?

Please help. Many Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add target for UIControlEventTouchDown for all your small buttons and call:

```
[self.largeButton setHighlighted:true];
```

Then add target for UIControlEventTouchUpInside and UIControlEventTouchUpOutside on the small buttons and call:

```
[self.largeButton setHighlighted:false];
```